# How to properly parameterize my postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection

I'm trying to parameterize my postgresql query in order to prevent SQL injection in my ruby on rails application. The SQL query will sum a different value in my table depending on the input.

Here is a simplified version of my function:

```
def self.calculate_value(value)
    calculated_value = ""
    if value == "quantity"
        calculated_value = "COALESCE(sum(amount), 0)"
    elsif value == "retail"
        calculated_value = "COALESCE(sum(amount * price), 0)"
    elsif value == "wholesale"
        calculated_value = "COALESCE(sum(amount * cost), 0)"
    end
    
    query = <<-SQL
        select CAST(? AS DOUBLE PRECISION) as ? from table1
    SQL
    return Table1.find_by_sql([query, calculated_value, value])
end
```

If I call `calculate_value("retail")`, it will execute the query like this:

```
select location, CAST('COALESCE(sum(amount * price), 0)' AS DOUBLE PRECISION) as 'retail' from table1 group by location
```

This results in an error. I want it to execute without the quotes like this:

```
select location, CAST(COALESCE(sum(amount * price), 0) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) as retail from table1 group by location
```

I understand that the addition of quotations is what prevents the sql injection but how would I prevent it in this case? What is the best way to handle this scenario?

**NOTE:** This is a simplified version of the queries I'll be writing and I'll want to use find_by_sql.

Comment: You need double-quotes for identifiers, single-quotes are or values.

Comment: Alias cannot be a parameter. Moreover, it must be a constant - dynamic output structure is not deterministic. Recommendation - create 3 separate final non-parametrized query texts and select one of them depends on parameter provided.

Answer (score 2):

Prepared statement can not change query structure: table or column names, order by clause, function names and so on. Only literals can be changed this way.

Where is SQL injection? You are not going to put a user-defined value in the query text. Instead, you check the given value against the allowed list and use only your own written parts of SQL. In this case, there is no danger of SQL injection.

---

I also want to link to [this article](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic). It is safe to create a query text dynamically if you control all parts of that query. And it's much better for RDBMS than some smart logic in query.